# PDO MySQL connection failure

Tags: php, html, mysqli

[A link to my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229797/php-to-mysql-secured-with-mysqli-and-hyperlink-redirect-not-working-once-submitt/46229872?noredirect=1#comment79425877_46229872)

This is my PHP code

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbame=$dbname",$user,$pass);
$UserN = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['UserN']);
$FullN = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['FullN']);
$Adrs = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Adrs']);
$Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Email']);
$PhoneN = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['PhoneN']);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO UserIn (UserN, FullN, Adrs, Email, 
PhoneN) VALUES ('$UserN','$FullN','$Adrs','$Email','$PhoneN')"); //Insert 
query $stmt->execute($UserN, $FullN, $Adrs, $Email, $PhoneN);



?>
```

And this is my form code

```
 <div class="form-con">
         <form action="insert.php" method="POST">
             <label>Username</label><br>
             <input type="text" name="UserN" placeholder="Your Username" ><br>
             <label>Full Name</label><br>
             <input type="text" name="FullN" placeholder="Full Name"><br>
             <label>Full Address</label><br>
             <textarea type="text" rows="4" cols="50" name="Adrs" placeholder="Address"></textarea><br> 
                  <label>Email Address</label><br>
                  <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address"><br>
                  <label>Phone Number</label><br>
                  <input type="text" name="PhoneN" placeholder="Phone Number"><br>
                   <div class="btn">
                     <a href="#"><button type="submit">Submit</button></a>
                   </div>
         </form>
      </div>
```

Upon clicking on the submit button I am provided with a and it provides me with This page isn’t working

xxxxxxxx.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: It means you have error on page so put this two line in top of page to on the debug mode `ini_set("display_errors", "On"); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: in the php files correct? I put it right after the first line and it still made no difference.

Comment: First of all your form page is loading or not ?

Comment: yes it is loading correctly do you think it would be wise to post a link to my site?

Comment: Remove everything in `insert.php` page just put this line `<?php echo "page working"; ?>`  - For testing purpose

Comment: it echoes back page working upon click on submit button

Comment: So problem is with your  php code  try to debug it . Your mixing mysqli with pdo . take some good tutorial and then code it .  did you noticed that there is no `$con` variable at all in your  code .

Comment: Why are you attempting to use both PDO and `mysqli_real_escape_string`? Where is `$con` coming from? Why aren't you binding parameters to your SQL statement? Why are you passing multiple arguments to `execute()`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly  try to rename your ".htaccess" to".htaccess-test" and then try to submit, OR use CHMOD 644 for the file and CHMOD 755 on folder(directories), if it continue, try this:

mysqli_real_escape_string doesn't work perfectly with Pdo and when you are using 
**"pdo prepare execute ou Query prepare"**, mysqli_real_escape_string is not important!!!

USE THIS CODE:

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbame=$dbname",$user,$pass);
extract($_POST);
$UserN =strip_tags($_POST['UserN']);
$FullN = strip_tags($_POST['FullN']);
$Adrs = strip_tags($_POST['Adrs']);
$Email = strip_tags($_POST['Email']);
$PhoneN = strip_tags($_POST['PhoneN']);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO UserIn (UserN, FullN, Adrs, Email, PhoneN) VALUES(:UserN, :FullN, :Adrs, :Email, :PhoneN)');
$stmt->execute(array(
             'UserN' => $UserN,
             'FullN' => $FullN,
             'Adrs' => $Adrs,
             'Email' => $Email,
             'PhoneN' => $PhoneN,  
));

?>
```

Comment: so this is how I would implement the second line correctly right

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$locahost;dbame=$idxxxx84_foxxxn",$idxxxx84_fxxxml,$xxxxx);